# I have world file to launch then should i include my urdf of robot model inside the world too?

Tags: urdf, sdf, gazebo7, ros-kinetic, world

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually, I'm creating a robot on my own .Now, what happened was when I launched the urdf file using the launch
something like this:

```
<launch>
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder '$(find 2wr)/urdf/two.xacro'" />
</launch>
```

The world in gazebo doesn't load with robot model. Now I was confused so I went on to add URDF of the robot into the world sdf and now robot appears in gazebo.
Wrote all the that I wrote in URDF file inside this "modeL" tag.

```
<model name='2wr'>
<link name........
..............</model>
```

So my question is should we have to describe the structure of robots both in URDF as well as SDF(i.e inside the WORLD file)??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390912/i-have-world-file-to-launch-then-should-i-include-my-urdf-of-robot-model-inside-the-world-too?/) by [sidharth.jeyabal](https://answers.ros.org/users/53096/sidharth.jeyabal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2021-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you use urdf_spawner node for robot appearing on Gazebo?
If you dont use, use bottom:

```
<node name="urdf_spawner" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" respawn="false" output="screen"
args="-urdf -model deneme_1 -param robot_description"/>
```

deneme_1: your robot name defined at urdf or .xacro

---

Originally posted by [muratkoc503](https://answers.ros.org/users/91043/muratkoc503/) with karma: 16 on 2021-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0